# PHP, Error 1136 : Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

I get this Exception:

```
Error 1136 : Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Structure of the table :

```
create table gb_entries (
    id int(4) not null auto_increment,
    username varchar(40) not null,
    name varchar(40),
    gender varchar(40),
    dob int(40),
    email varchar(40),
    primary key (id) 
);
```

With this PHP code:

```
// Add a new entry to the database
function addEntry($username, $name, $gender, $dob, $email) {
  $connection = mysql_open();
  $insert = "insert into gb_entries " . 
      "values ('$username', '$name', '$gender', '$dob', '$email')";
  $result = @ mysql_query ($insert, $connection)
      or showerror();
  mysql_close($connection)
      or showerror();
}

// Return an array of database entries that contain $name anad $email
function getEntries($username,$name,$gender,$dob,$email) {
  // Sanitise user input to prevent SQL injection attacks
  $username = mysql_escape_string($username);
  $name = mysql_escape_string($name);
  $gender = mysql_escape_string($gender);
  $dob = mysql_escape_string($dob);
  $email = mysql_escape_string($email);


  // Open connection and select database
  $connection = mysql_open();

  // Construct query
  $query = 
    "select username, name, gender, dob, email from gb_entries where 0=0 ";
  if (! empty($username)) {
      $query .= "AND username LIKE '%$username%' ";
  }
   if (! empty($name)) {
      $query .= "AND name LIKE '%$name%' ";
  }
  if (! empty($gender)) {
      $query .= "AND gender LIKE '%$gender%' ";
  }
  if (! empty($dob)) {
      $query .= "AND dob LIKE '%$dob%' ";
  }
  if (! empty($email)) {
      $query .= "AND email LIKE '%$email%' ";
  }


  $query .= "ORDER BY id";
  // echo $query;

  // Execute query
  $result = @ mysql_query($query, $connection)
      or showerror();

  // Transform the result set to an array (for Smarty)
  $entries = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $entries[] = $row;
  }

  mysql_close($connection)
      or showerror();
  return $entries;
}
```

What does the Exception mean?

Comment: Hi! You can format your code by putting 4 spaces before each line *(the `{}` button, on top of the editor, does just that)* ; I've done it for you, this time ;; for more informations about formating your posts, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 7):

As it says, the column count doesn't match the value count. You're providing five values on a six column table. Since you're not providing a value for `id`, as it's auto increment, it errors out - you need to specify the specific columns you're inserting into:

```
$insert = "insert into gb_entries (username, name, gender, dob, email) " . 
      "values ('$username', '$name', '$gender', '$dob', '$email')"
```

Also, I really hate that `WHERE 0=0` line. I know *why* you're doing it that way, but I personally find it cleaner to do something like this (warning: air code!):

```
$query = "select username, name, gender, dob, email from gb_entries ";

$where = array();
if (! empty($username)) {
      $where[] = "username LIKE '%$username%'"; // add each condition to an array
// repeat for other conditions

// create WHERE clause by combining where clauses, 
// adding ' AND ' between conditions, 
// and append this to the query if there are any conditions 
if (count($where) > 0) {
  $query .= "WHERE " . implode($where, " AND "); 
}
```

This is personal preference, as the query optimizer would surely strip out the `0=0` on it's own and so it wouldn't have a performance impact, but I just like my SQL to have as few hacks as possible.

Comment: That's going to produce an invalid query if there are no where clauses. You need to check the `$where` array count before appending to the query.

Comment: @Phil: I caught the `implode` part before your comment, but not the hanging 'WHERE' with no conditions. You'll note I *did* intend to handle this, as I create the array beforehand to be sure it exists, but forgot to add the actual check in when I wrote that section. I'll add that in now. Thanks.

Comment: @Phil: I added the `count()` check. Is there anything else I missed?

Answer (score 2):

If the error is occurring when trying to insert a row to your table, try specifying the list of fields, in the insert query -- this way, the number of data in the `values` clause will match the number of expected columns.

Else, MySQL expects six columns : it expects the `id` column -- for which you didn't specify a value.

Basically, instead of this :

```
$insert = "insert into gb_entries " . 
  "values ('$username', '$name', '$gender', '$dob', '$email')";
```

Use something like that :

```
$insert = "insert into gb_entries (username, name, gender, dob, email) " . 
  "values ('$username', '$name', '$gender', '$dob', '$email')";
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The column count was correct. the problem was that i was trying to save a String (the value had quotes around it) in an INT field. So your problem is probably coming from the single quotes you have around the '$dob'. I know, the mysql error generated doesn't make sense..

funny thing, I had the same problem again.. and found my own answer here (quite embarrassingly)
It's an UNEXPECTED Data problem (sounds like  better error msg to me). I really think, that error message should be looked at again

Answer (score 0):

Does modifying this line help?

```
$insert = "insert into gb_entries (username, name, gender, dob, email) " . 
      "values ('$username', '$name', '$gender', '$dob', '$email')";
```